# How to replace fragment , which already has some view?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I have this fragment_settings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearlayout_settings_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_my_account"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="My Account" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_my_account_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="List" />

</LinearLayout>
```

with following code:

```
public class SettingsFragment extends Fragment implements Constants, OnClickListener{

    public static SettingsFragment newInstance() {
        SettingsFragment f = new SettingsFragment();
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        container.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, container,
                false);
        initViews(view);
        return view;
    }

    private void initViews(View view) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        TextView textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textview_my_account);
        textView.setOnClickListener(this);
        TextView textView1 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textview_my_account_1);
        textView1.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.textview_my_account:
            SettingsContactDetailFragment settingsContactDetailFragment = SettingsContactDetailFragment.newInstance();
            settingsContactDetailFragment.setRetainInstance(true);
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.linearlayout_settings_fragment, settingsContactDetailFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(FragmentEnum.SETTINGS_CONTACT_DETAIL_FRAGMENT);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            break;

        case R.id.textview_my_account_1:
            SettingsContactListFragment settingsContactListFragment = SettingsContactListFragment.newInstance();
            settingsContactListFragment.setRetainInstance(true);
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.linearlayout_settings_fragment, settingsContactListFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(FragmentEnum.SETTINGS_CONTACT_LIST_FRAGMENT);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

i tried this working. But when i use **fragmentTransaction.replace** then fragment is added with views which are already in fragment_settings.xml

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.linearlayout_settings_fragment);
linearLayout.removeAllViews();
```

**but why below not work ?**

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.linearlayout_settings_fragment, settingsContactListFragment);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[FragmentTransaction.replace](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace%28int,%20android.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String%29) method removes only the previously added Fragment's view from the container. It does not remove all the views belonging to the container. That's why it gets appended to the other 2 `TextViews`.

If you want to replace the `TextView`, then they should be part of another `Fragment`, which can be added to `R.id.linearlayout_settings_fragment` initially and latter replace it with `SettingsContactDetailFragment` or `SettingsContactListFragment` fragments.

Comment: ok , thanks . So these two textview consider as a part of another fragment which should not be replaced/removed by **.replace** method. Need to add these two views in fragment and then replace with other fragment